# How to get products name insade all arrray?

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1iOKA.png)ı want to set custom event with gtm but ı dont know how to get multple producs name . ı can get one of the items name but ı can not get all of them.

```
document.getElementsByClassName('cartAndCheckout__items')[0].innerText.split('\nStokta var\n3.329,00 TL')[0]
```

[image]
[image]

thats the code ı wrote

Answer (score 3):

Seems you just need to iterate the elements that you find via `document.getElementsByClassName`

```
let products = []
let elements = document.getElementsByClassName('cartAndCheckout__items')
for(let i=0; i<elements.length; i++){
  //products.push(elements[i].innerText)

  //based on your comment,if you just want to get the name
  let link = elements[i].querySelector('div.mb-2 a')
  let title = link.getAttribute("title")
  products.push(title)
}
```

Comment: That may not work because `forEach` is not defined on element collections, which aren't actually Arrays.

Comment: @MarkReed Thanks for pointing out,I just tested it and you are right

Comment: thank you for your answer but that code just gave me total item number at basket page. ı want all items name

Comment: @miraçreisoğlu You need to provide more inforamtion about what's your product like

Comment: ı add basket page you can see what kind of page that is

Comment: @miraçreisoğlu we need to expand it in order to get the structure of your element

Comment: ı expand one of items element

Comment: @miraçreisoğlu Where do you want to get the name,`title` or `text`,both seems work

Comment: yeah thats right title or text  one of them will be fine

Comment: @miraçreisoğlu See my updated code, since I do not fully know the element structure,it might not work,then you need to change by yourself

Comment: its give me '}' unexcepted token error

Comment: @miraçreisoğlu it has nothing to do with my answer code,you need check it in your side

Comment: ı was trying to get all text from all node list but something gone wrong everytime with my code , ı added new img can you look at it one more time pls

Comment: @miraçreisoğlu As I said yesterday,`} unexpected token` means there are some syntax error in your code,you need to check your code

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementsByClassName('cartAndCheckout__items')` returns a collection; it looks and mostly works like an array, even though it isn't an `Array`. You're getting the first item with `[0]`, but you can also for instance loop over all the items:

```
let products = []
for (const element of document.getElementsByClassName('cartAndCheckout__items')) {
  products.push(element.innerText.split('\nStokta var\n3.329,00 TL')[0])
}
```

Usually if you're building one list from another it's better to use `map`, but as the collection isn't actually an Array, you have to call it in a roundabout way:

```
const elements = document.getElementsByClassName('cartAndCheckout__items')
const products = Array.prototype.map.call(elements,
   e => e.innerText.split('\nStokta var\n3.329,00 TL')[0])
```

Comment: ı just wanna get innerHTML from all node list

Answer (score 0):

Please note that ES6 is not supported in GTM, thus you either need to translate the above solution (which is basicly replace "const" and "let" with var :D) or implement the JavaScript natively and push the result to the DataLayer.